# How do I reinstalling docusaurus 2.0.0-beta.15

Tags: docusaurus

I am have problems with 2.0.0-beta.16 failing to build on Cloudflare. How do I reinstall 2.0.0-beta.15

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The same code deployed to Cloudflare with 2.0.0-beta.15 that works, is being deployed to Cloudflare to test Docusaurus 2.0.0-beta.16 and fails. All I am asking is how do I reinstall 2.0.0-beta.15. I have searched but have not been successful.